# Chat is unreachable from some locations

Tags: bug, chat

Stack Exchange works fine, but I haven't been able to reach chat for about three years now. Even given the IP address, I can't ping the server.

The problem seems specific to me. I use Smart Broadband of the Philippines. I can't reach any IP addresses in the block assigned to the chat ISP, Peak Internet.

Perhaps raise the issue with the ISP or migrate to a better-connected server?

Comment: What is that page supposed to look like for locations chat is inaccessible from? I see [0% packet loss across the board and two dashes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lQYmP.png).

Comment: @AnnaLear I assume the dashes mean unreachability.

Comment: I'd expect to see 100% packet loss.

Comment: … on second thought, though, those locations fail the test even for google.com, so I didn't really test carefully enough.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not dismissing your report outright. Just not sure how to interpret that test.

Comment: @AnnaLear Well, plugging in a bogus address generates all dashes. I think a dash indicates 100% loss, but they decide not to include that in the average.

Comment: @AnnaLear on that screenshot Amsterdam is one of the dashes and I can assure you chat works fine for me (and my connection passes AMS-IX for sure)....just to let you know ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best thing to do is call Smart and let them know that you're unable to reach the IP. It's a routing issue on their end, and they're probably not even aware of it, because nobody has complained about it. I'd need a traceroute from your IP to chat in order to tell you *precisely* where it's breaking down, but I'm willing to bet it's at their border routers and the issue is with their BGP config. [Contact us privately](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) to give us the information.

I'm *not* able to reproduce this using my Smart Bro post-paid (pocket wifi) from Mandaluyong or Makati, so it's definitely something you'll need to call them about. Just be sure to have the block ready, as well as the hostname where the traceroute *stops*, and they'll fix it.

The good thing about Smart is decent customer service, in my experience they fix things quickly without all the "have you turned it off and on again?" bit.

In the meantime, you can *probably* get around this using [Hola](http://hola.org/), provided that you're able to connect to their free VPN server. I used it frequently when Sky Cable wasn't dealing with web sockets very well, and it works quite reliably.

Comment: Hmm, the pings disappear inside Smart's network. Odd that it's been consistently different from such nearby locations. I'll send a mail to that address, it sounds like their service is better there than here.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Just to rule out something as silly as DNS cache, can you let me know what IP you're getting when you ping chat? They might be sending you to the wrong datacenter based on a very stale record. Alternately, try switching your resolvers to 4.2.2.2 / 4.2.2.3 and let me know if that works.

Comment: The IP is 69.59.197.29. I sent a message with full details using the contact page.

Comment: Ping… someone elsewhere on the Net just cited a reference to the C++ chat-log and I can't see it!

Comment: It's fixed now, thanks!